# Why doesn't Nine use his Legacies in the West Virginia Mogadorian base?

Tags: lorien-legacies

> In *The Lost Files: Nine's Legacy* (chapter 22), Nine is forced to watch Sandor being tortured in the West Virginia Mogadorian base.
>  Why doesn't he use his telekinesis to stop this from happening? What's stopping him from mentally pushing the Mogadorian torturer away from Sandor, or turning the Mog's blade against him?
> There is only a force field between Nine and Sandor.

In *United As One* we learn that Legacies can be used through force fields - I can't find what chapter it's in, but Six creates a storm inside the *Anubis*'s force field when she's outside of it.

Nine develops his telekinesis long before this chapter, so is this just an oversight by the authors? Or is the emotional stress of the situation too much for him to concentrate enough to use his Legacies?

When Nine does break through the force field, he tries to use his telekinesis immediately, implying that he didn't think he could before. There's no mention I can find of trying to use it beforehand, though.

Perhaps telekinesis is an exception that can't be used through force fields. I can only speculate, though.

> Is there anything that can explain Nine not using his telekinesis to defend Sandor?

Comment: Added spoiler markup to the body and slightly reworded the question. Should be less spoileriffic now.

Comment: maybe anything in your speculates above, we may never know along lot of things through the books

Comment: He could have either been not experienced enough to know about force fields and how legacies operate through them. Or telekinesis could not work through fields because it seems to be a more physical force than the other legacies.